# Travel insurance against death in Europe

Tags: legal, insurance

Generally, **does travel insurance cover death?** (I mean such that the beneficiary would get a lump sum, €100,000 or whatever you signed up for, in the case of accidental death while on the holiday.) If not true in general, **is such a thing available at all** and if so, where can it be found?

Comment: If you're concerned about dying and your family needing money, given that holidays aren't normally much more risky than living at home, would you not be better off taking out a general Life Insurance policy?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding you. If you're worried about how your family would survive financially if you died, then how would it be any different if the (say) car accident was while you were on holiday, as opposed to on your way to work on a normal non-holiday day? i.e. what's special about your travels that means you'd like extra insurance for it happening then?

Comment: If you update your question to make clear that you already have some life insurance, and want extra, then I'll delete my comments. If you have some other specific reason for wanting extra cover when travelling, put it in the question. If not, I'll be minded to answer explaining how travelling in Europe is pretty safe on a global scale, and how you'd be better off with Life Insurance to protect you in general and not just when travelling around Europe

Comment: @JoeBlow there is however a difference. You take extra health insurance because often international health coverage is not covered in national plans. Same with theft insurance, there is a higher risk when traveling. Travel insurance is specifically designed to cover additional risks not covered by normal insurance. In the case of life insurance, you simply cover the repatriation part, not the lumpsum to cover economic losses. That is covered by a normal life insurance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes such insurances exist. However you didn't say where you are located. If you simply want an example I can point you to an example in the [Netherlands](https://www.ing.nl/particulier/verzekeren/reisverzekering/doorlopende-reisverzekering/basisdekking-doorlopende-reisverzekering.aspx) (link is Dutch). They cover

> Per verzekerde (overlijden/blijvende invaliditeit)    € 5.000/€ 50.000
>   Als gevolg van besturen van motorrijwiel (overlijden/blijvende invaliditeit)  € 5.000/€ 25.000

If you die your relatives will get 5000, if you get permanently injured you'll get 50.000. 
Again to get this insurance you need to live in the Netherlands.

I know of a travel insurer that can be bought [online](http://www.axa-schengen.com/en). They do cover death, but not the lump sum case you are looking for. It is more ["Assistance in case of death"](http://www.axa-schengen.com/subscribe/downloads/europe_travel/cg_axa_schengen_europe_travel_uk.pdf).

Maybe you can combine such a travel insurance with a life insurance?

Answer (score 3):

**Some Travel Insurances do cover death. However it's likely possible that not all types of travel insurances cover it.**

For some personal experience, my travel insurance covers a large amount in case of death, but my insurance is a student travel insurance valid for one year.

In case of smaller duration of travel, it's probably unlikely to be mentioned separately but I am certain both kinds of plans are available.

As of now I'm unable to find specific examples for you because that depends on a couple of factors such as your citizenship, country of travel etc.

Comment: "Some Travel Insurances do cover death".  Right - that's the question.  Does anyone know any?

Comment: @JoeBlow for example, world nomads, an insurance for travelers, offers some amount if you die in an accident during your trip. The exact sum is not precise, but from 2000 euros for someone under 18 up to 150000 euros: http://www.worldnomads.com/policy_wording.aspx?pid=4b477ca754c1478bbf5c760eb2d1931d#Section26

Comment: @JoeBlow I could have pointed them to a link to my insurance, but that would be quite pointless IMO. The OP needs to provide more information for an exact answer.

Comment: @JoeBlow I just looked at my travel insurance which is an economy package from Protect Your Bubble (I am in the UK). Their cheapest package offers £2500 death benefit for over 18s. Their most expensive package offers £25000. They also offer money for loss of limbs (£5000-£50000) or permanent total disablement (again £5000-£50000).